# How to create JavaScript Tabs from to iterate over a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've Tab design like that. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/genxer34/657joa4h/)

And this is my JavaScript Object sample. The titles of the tabs will consist of categories by this JavaScript Object. But some product is has two categories and then this product will be inside that two category. I'm sorry if it's complicated. I had to write a little fast.

How to iterate category and product and integrate this tabs?

For example

Tabs1 = Coffee

Content= Product1, Product3, Product7

[image]

```
var product = [{
        "product_name": "Product 1",
        "product_id": "8991",
        "product_price": "$69",
        categories: [{
            categoryName: 'Tea'
        }, {
            categoryName: 'Coffee'
        }],

    },

    {
        "product_name": "Product 2",
        "product_id": "8951",
        "product_price": "29 TL",
        categories: [{
            categoryName: 'Tea'
        }]


    },
    {
        "product_name": "Product 3",
        "product_id": "8941",
        "product_new_price": "79 TL",
        categories: [{
            categoryName: 'Gift'
        }, {
            categoryName: 'Coffee'
        }],




    },
    {
        "product_name": "Product 4",
        "product_id": "8931",
        "product_new_price": "39 TL",
        categories: [{
            categoryName: 'Gift'
        }, {
            categoryName: 'Tea'
        }],



    },
    {
        "product_name": "Product 5",
        "product_id": "8911",
        "product_new_price": "49 TL",
        categories: [{
            categoryName: 'Gift'
        }],



    },
    {
        "product_name": "Product 6",
        "product_id": "8971",
        "product_old_price": "89 TL",
        "product_new_price": "59 TL",
        categories: [{
            categoryName: 'Toys'
        }, {
            categoryName: 'Gift'
        }, {
            categoryName: 'Tea'
        }],


    },
    {
        "product_name": "Product 7",
        "product_id": "8921",
        "product_new_price": "69 TL",
        categories: [{
            categoryName: 'Coffe'
        }, {
            categoryName: 'Kahve'
        }],


    },
    {
        "product_name": "Product 8",
        "product_id": "8431",
        "product_new_price": "19 TL",
        "categories": "Food"


    }
    ];
```

Comment: Where are you getting the product array from? Can it have more than 3 categories? can it also include an array of categories only? Can you make categories an array, instead of a comma separated string?

Comment: I'm creating manually my array. Yes it can be more than 3 categories sometimes I'm updated example and categories array is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the attribute data for the tabs with the category name. When you click on a tab, you get the attribute value and use the function to get products

```
function getProducts(products = [], categoryName = 'Gift') {
    let result = [];

    for (let product of products) {
        if (product.categories === undefined || !Array.isArray(product.categories)) {
            break;
        }

        for (let category of product.categories) {
            if (category.categoryName === categoryName) {
                result.push(product);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then paste the received data into the content

Comment: Can you basic sample on my fiddle example? thnx https://jsfiddle.net/genxer34/657joa4h/

Comment: Thanks for fiddle example. But first tab is not fill the data? when I click second and after click first tab then filling